# MySQL: How to get all values in "TICKER" column`?

Tags: mysql

I never used SQL before, I want to get all values in "TICKER" from this database:

[image]

The first statement

`select TDATE, price, return1 from STOCK_DATA where TDATE < 20131231 and TDATE > 20121231 and TICKER = 'IBM'`

works fine for a single 'IBM' ticker.

However, I want to have the list of all tickers in this table, but `select TICKER from STOCK_DATA` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you want *one* row per `TICKER`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TICKER FROM STOCK_DATA;
```

Comment: Thanks yes! As follow up, I need a table with "TDATE" as row and "return1" for each distinct ticker in column, so that I get like a table with all tickers and their return series from 20131231-20121231? It would be sth. like "select return1 from STOCK_DATA where TDATE < 20131231 and TDATE > 20121231 and COLUMNSHOWS TICKER"